# How to wait for Angular components to initialize before executing code present in ngOnInit in Cypress test case

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm writing Cypress test cases for an Angular application, and I need to ensure that certain code, specifically present in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook of Angular components, has executed before proceeding with the test. How can I wait for Angular components to initialize properly within my Cypress test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see what exactly is going on in your lifecycle hooks its hard to say exactly what you can do. with that being said there are some things you can do depending on your setup.

One thing that we do is while we are waiting for our ngOnInit's to run and finish we have a loading spinner up and we hook into that to 1) verify that that the loading spinner exists, then 2) give a 30 second timeout for the spinner to not exists. then you know the ngOnInit is finished.

```
cy.get('loading-spinner').should('exist');
cy.get('loading-spinenr').should('not.exist', { timeout: 30000 });
```

if you dont have a loading spinner while running through your lifecycle hooks, is there anything on your view that changes that you can wait for to determine that you are finished with the lifecycle?